# Procedural CSS Generation in PHP and Browser Cacheing

Tags: php, html, css, caching, browser-cache

I like to generate CSS constants using PHP and I'm wondering if there's a way to do this that will still leverage cacheing.  Right now I'm defining everything in the index.php file and while it's a web app and so the extra 20-80kb of css isn't toooooo relevant, it would be nice to have it cached so my question is twofold:

- What's the most optimal way to generate CSS using PHP (or a similarly cross-browser solution that doesn't need to render using JS ala LESS or SASS)
- Does the procedural generation of CSS values using PHP get ignored by the end-browser if the values are unchanged?  In other words, if I don't touch the layout for a month and somebody visits twice in that month, does the very fact that PHP is outputting the data break cacheing or, so long as the data is identical, will the cache still be respected by most modern browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: to cache css why not use .htaccess file?

Comment: I thought CSS was cached by default?